# how can i add a gradle exec task with properties?

Tags: bash, gradle, build.gradle

i have a problem with a gradle exec task.
code:

```
task startup {
  final GradleVersion gradleVersion = GradleVersion.current()
  println "##### start script #####"
  println "gradle version: ${gradleVersion}"
  println "project: ${project.group}.fmp-${project.name}-${project.version}"
}

task create(type: Exec) {
  workingDir "./scripts"
  commandLine "./create_service_from_template.sh", sn, gwv
}
```

So when I execute `gradle create -Psn=test -Pgwv=4.0` then it works. 
but when I start another task (like `gradle startup` then an error appears: 
`Could not get unknown property 'sn' for task ':create' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.`

I thought I can put the lines in the create Task into a `doLast` block, but then it doesn't work.

Can some one help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Gradle will run the *Configuration* phase on all tasks.

One fix is to use local variables which are initialized with a check to see if the property was specified. See the beginning:

```
def sn = project.hasProperty('sn') ? project.sn : ''
def gwv = project.hasProperty('gwv') ? project.gwv : ''

task startup {
  final GradleVersion gradleVersion = GradleVersion.current()
  println "##### start script #####"
  println "gradle version: ${gradleVersion}"
  println "project: ${project.group}.fmp-${project.name}-${project.version}"
}

task create(type: Exec) {
  workingDir "./scripts"
  commandLine "./create_service_from_template.sh", sn, gwv
}
```

Comment: that helps. I put the two variable definitions also into the create task. thank you!